# Errors while running rCharts and gvisMotinChart

Tags: r, slidify, rpres

I have tried to build a presentation with slidify package in R. I have coded the presentation and called slidify function on the following .Rmd file. I have used the diamonds dataset in GGally.

When I published the following , n1$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE) is not displaying the rChart.

Error in object$show(): object 'opts_current' not found

gvisMotionChart is also showing errors.

I was wondering and expecting rCharts and gvisMotionChart, I am missing something. Thanks in anticipation.

````
 ---
 title       : Presentation
 subtitle    : 
 author      : 
 job         : 
 framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
 highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
 hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
 widgets     : [mathjax, quiz, bootstrap,shiny,interactive]  # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
 mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
 knit        : slidify::knit2slides

 --- &interactive

 ```{r}
 library(rCharts)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(GGally)
 n1 <- nPlot(carat ~ cut , group = "color", data = diamonds[1:40,], type = "multiBarChart")
 n1$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE)

 ```
 --- &interactive

 ## Plot 

 ```{r opts.label = 'interactive'}
 library(googleVis)
 library(GGally)
 g  <-gvisMotionChart(diamonds, "carat", "price", options = list(width = 800, height = 600))
 g$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE)

 ```
````